# How to set up rotational full and incremental innobackupex?

Tags: mysql, linux, backup, percona, innobackupex

Innobackupex provides both full and incremental backup of mysql servers.

But i am looking for a script that automate the process of daily full backup and incremental in certain hours.

The script will remove old backup files and mail the status etc.
Any idea or readymade script ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Nothing ready-made that I am aware of. You should just code this yourself in bash and call the script from cron. Use `find . -type d -mtime +5 -maxdepth 1 -exec rm -r {} \;` to remove backups older than 5 days. Incremental backups using innobackupex are based on a full backup so you need to be able to reference that directory in your script. I've written many of these for my clients (I work for Percona), so it isn't hard. Shouldn't be more than 20-30 lines of bash.